# How to type em-dash with a croatian keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard

I have Catalina and a Mac Air 2017.

No matter what I try, I can't get the em-dash. I tried everything on the forum, nothing worked. All I keep getting is that upside-down question mark. I have a Croatian keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2):

¿ is exactly what you are supposed to get with option shift minus on the Apple Croatian input source.

To see which key does what, use [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/11.0/mac/11.0).

em dash is option y