# Unable to type special characters through Screen Sharing on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina, screen-sharing

After Updating from MacOS 10.14 Mojave to MacOS 10.15 Catalina I cannot type special characters on a remote machine connected via the Screen Sharing APP.
All special characters evoked with the option Key are wrong.
Instead of "–" I get "¿".
Until 10.14 everythings worked fine. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: What is the macOS version of the machine you sit with a physical keyboard and what  is the version on the one that is remote?

Comment: I'm working from 10.15 Catalina to the remote machine running 10.14 ...

Comment: Maybe I'll help to update the remote machine to 10.15, too?

Comment: Not sure. Wanted to try and reproduce it first.

Comment: What language are both Macs set to? opt/shift/- is m-dash in English, but ¿ in other languages, Croatian, for instance [I only know this because it cropped up in another QA recently - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427517/how-to-type-em-dash-with-a-croatian-keyboard-layout

Comment: Both macs are set to german, ¿ is usually a spanish character ...

Comment: What physical key location are you pressing? I have a UK keyboard here, where all the dash keys are right of zero 0 on the numbers row. If I set it to German, then they all move to the bottom row, left of Shift; and 0 is replaced by ß. Opt/ß gives ¿ ..though by now I've just about confused myself ;)) https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Un9.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt97N.png

Comment: What do the two machines have set in system preferences > keyboard > input sources.  That is what matters.  ¿ is available on most keyboards someplace, including German.  If you are getting that instead of em dash, it sounds like the other end is set to US instead of German.

Comment: Both machines have a german keyboard configured.

Comment: Usually opt+"-" would look like: "–". (this is not the em-dash)
But you get ¿ instead, which is usually opt + "ß".

The error only occurs with the Screen Sharing App, not with ARD. And only unter 10.15...

Comment: You are right it is not the em dash, it is the en dash, U+2013.  Sorry for the mistake.  Strange the machine at the other end should behave as if the US layout were active if that layout is not present in the input sources list.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that on the remote machine, system preferences > keyboard > input sources has only "German" on the list (and not US or something else).

Comment: That is the case ... On both the remote and the observing machine.

How about 10.14 or Apple Remote Desktop: In both cases it works fine. Since the Screen Sharing App hasn't change between 10.14/Mojave and 10.15/Catalina there must some issue with 10.15 ...
I'll try to update the remote system to 10.15, maybe that'll help

Comment: @Stefan I found this report of a possibly related issue :  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251592382

Comment: Just updated a remote client to 10.15 / Catalina.
Now all the divis characters seem to work as designed, even when typed with screen sharing app.
-
–
—
Seems to be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could open "Character Viewer" on the remote machine. It's located on the menu bar.
If not, you can activate it by going to

System Preferences > Keyboard > Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar

If you have multiple keyboard languages, it'll be under the country flag.

[image: option to be checked on the system preference]

Then click on it and select "Show Emoji & Symbols"

[image: show emoji & symbols on the menu bar]

There are several columns, I imagine the characters you're looking for are under the Latin

From there, you can double click on any character and it will appear on any open text fields.

[image: character viewer window]

Comment: Thank you DeepBlue,
our editors & journalists need to reach the most important special characters on the (german) keytab ...
Some characters like correct quotes ("99" , "66", en-dash) are used so often, that picking them out of a character map would be awfully timeconsuming. 
But for the more rare characters like appearing in Names this is very comfortable  possibility!