# How can I prevent my Mac from relocking the screen when disconnecting from a remote desktop session?

Tags: apple-remote-desktop

I share a single keyboard across multiple computers, so sometimes my Mac does not have a keyboard attached. I'd like to still lock the screen when I'll be away from the computer, however when I get back I find myself unable to unlock it via Remote Desktop via my MacBook (due to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427618/unable-to-type-special-characters-through-screen-sharing-on-macos-catalina) issue - my password involves special characters). I figured out I *can* unlock it using the VNC app on my phone. However as soon as I disconnect, the screen gets locked again. I'd like the screen to remain unlocked after disconnecting.

Comment: I'd be tempted to just change the password to something that doesn't need the special characters. I can confirm that if the Mac was locked at any time, then every new or repeat connection must sign in again. If it was unlocked *on the Mac itself*, not from a remote, then it will stay unlocked through multiple reconnects [assuming, of course, that the remote is using the same account as is already active].